# php-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, centos7

I am stacked with following errors on my site when I test 200 hits per second.

First I received 499 errors

> 2017-04-09 03:22:45   Error   162.158.79.219  499 GET / HTTP/1.1  0   nginx access
>
> 2017-04-09 03:22:45   Error   162.158.79.87   499 GET / HTTP/1.1  0   nginx access
>
> 2017-04-09 03:22:45   Error   162.158.78.170  499 GET / HTTP/1.1  0   nginx access
>
> 2017-04-09 03:22:45   Error   162.158.78.68   499 GET / HTTP/1.1  0   nginx access

2nd Error start showing 502

> 2017-04-09 03:22:45   Error   162.158.79.135  502 GET / HTTP/1.1  166     nginx access
>
> 2017-04-09 03:22:45   Error   162.158.79.225  502 GET / HTTP/1.1  166     nginx access
>
> 2017-04-09 03:22:45   Error   162.158.78.110  502 GET / HTTP/1.1  166     nginx access
>
> 2017-04-09 03:22:45   Error   162.158.79.225  502 GET / HTTP/1.1  166     nginx access

and Finally I start receiving `php-fpm.sock failed` errors

> 2017-04-09 03:22:45    Error   162.158.79.207      20699#0: *3826365 connect() to unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/playhdpk.top/php-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream               nginx error
>
> 2017-04-09 03:22:45    Error   162.158.79.207      20695#0: *3826367 connect() to unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/playhdpk.top/php-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream               nginx error
>
> 2017-04-09 03:22:45    Error   162.158.79.207      20697#0: *3826369 connect() to unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/playhdpk.top/php-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream               nginx error

My `php-fpm-pool-settings` are below, I believe this one is being generating errors may I am wrong

```
listen.backlog = 65535

;[php-fpm-pool-settings]
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5000
pm.start_servers = 50
pm.min_spare_servers = 20
pm.max_spare_servers = 70
pm.max_requests = 2000
```

My `nginx` conf are below

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes 8;

# number of file descriptors used for nginx
# the limit for the maximum FDs on the server is usually set by the OS.
# if you don't set FD's then OS settings will be used which is by default 2000
worker_rlimit_nofile 99999;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;

include /etc/nginx/modules.conf.d/*.conf;

events {

    worker_connections 16192;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}


http {
    include   mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    open_file_cache max=2048 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 5;
    open_file_cache_errors off;


    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_requests 100000;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    client_body_timeout 30;
    send_timeout 15;

    client_header_timeout 12;
    proxy_connect_timeout  600s;
    proxy_send_timeout  600s;
    proxy_read_timeout  600s;

    fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;

    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types application/x-javascript text/css application/javascript text/javascript text/plain text/xml application/json application/v$
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";


    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

**Note**: Server specifications are below

OS CentOS 7.3

Processor: Intel Xeon E5-1620v2 - 4c/8t - 3.7 GHz/3.9 GH

Sever Ram: 64GB DDR3

Comment: This is the best solution thread I've found for this issue so far: [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/lemp-wordpress-php5-fpm-sock-failed](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/lemp-wordpress-php5-fpm-sock-failed)

Answer (score 23):

If I could downvote the answer from @Artsiom forever, I would.

`pm.max_children = 4000` means up to 4K worker processes. If traffic flows in very fast and together with `pm.max_requests = 0`, the workers are never recycled, the RAM usage will grow indefinitely over time and the server will be in out of memory condition (down, frozen) sooner or later.

PHP-FPM max_children should be raised carefully and gradually while monitoring swap usage.

You can use a formula liks the following:

```
pm.max_children = ((total RAM in MB) - (how much MySQL and others take in RAM)) / 80
```

Where 80 MB is average weight of a PHP-FPM workers process if your PHP framework is light. For heavy things like Magento 2, take at least 128 MB instead.

And the `pm.max_requests` should be some "limited" value.
In higher spec servers you can indeed raise it (10000, for example), while on low end servers this should be set to smallest (e.g. 500, to even 100) to reduce RAM "usage" fluctuations. But it no scenario I would set it to 0 (unlimited) because a value of 0 implies that your code / PHP and all of its extensions are absolutely free from memory leaks. Only then it would be fine to be set to 0!!!

Comment: Well I will give you an upvote for your great explanation. Any suggestions for settings like `pm.max_children` on a low traffic setup that is slowly growing in trafic?

Comment: `pm.max_children` should follow the same calculations, irrespective of the traffic. For nearly zero traffic, you want to have `pm` set to `ondemand` so that if no traffic, there are no worker processes at all.

Comment: how'd you get the `(how much MySQL and others take in RAM)`

Comment: @KimCarlo  You can use `mysqltuner` to see the max memory footprint possible for your MySQL configuration.

Answer (score 16):

This happens because the operating system rejects nginx's attempts to connect to a unix socket.

The reason is either the maximum number of socket connections or the maximum number of unhandled socket connections has been exceeded.

Checking the limits:

```
sysctl net.core
```

We are interested in the lines:

```
net.core.somaxconn = 128
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 200
```

Because of them, an error occurs, since the maximum number of connections is 128 and the maximum number of unprocessed is 200

Change the limits,  write the lines in the / etc / sysctl.conf file

```
nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

add

```
net.core.somaxconn = 20000
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 65535
```

Apply parameters

```
sysctl -p
```

Restart php-fpm

```
service php-fpm restart
```

Source: https://galaxydata.ru/community/sock-failed-11-resource-temporarily-unavailable-459

Answer (score -4):

Do not limit requests
Give them work free)

```
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 4000
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_requests = 0
```

Comment: This makes no sense. max_requests is jsut to occasionally recycle children. 2k should be plenty to not have issues.

Comment: Thanks, saved me a lot of $.

Comment: @jgmjgm not only it makes no sense, it's also dangerous and completely irrational. The upvoters here applied `Artsiom`'s suggestion only to gain grief later. See my answer with an explanation.